# How to suspend a close button functionality for a while?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying find a way to disable functionality of a Close button where I want. By using a MFC Library, firstly I defined a dialog window and a button considered to close the dialog with the following code:

```
void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        CDialog::OnOK();

    }
```

I tried to define a bool flag with two stats of TRUE and FALSE as follows:

```
 void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedOk(bool Flag)
    {
        If(Flage == TRUE){
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
            CDialog::OnOK();
    }
        }
```

where after a Flage= TRUE call, that button works and when this Flage= FALSE that button be disabled till a certain value of time. Compiler gives a syntax error because of incompatible arguments;

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &MyDlg::OnBnClickedOk(bool Flag))
```

For Enabling and Disabling this button,firstly this code included:

```
GetDlgItem(IDOK)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
```

It works well but the problem of this method is the drawn bitmap image over the button which disappears

**Edit:**

[image: After writing EnableWindow function]

[image]

In the .rc file there exist these line of codes for the button:

```
 PUSHBUTTON      "",IDOK,634,1,25,22,BS_BITMAP | BS_CENTER | BS_VCENTER
IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "D:\\Project\\Close.bmp"
```

Comment: You don't need to implement the logic inside the *button clicked* handler. When you disable a control, it will not generate any input. Calling `EnableWindow` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes,`EnableWindow` is sufficient but the problem is that removes the bitmap image which assigned for this button and this is not acceptable to design a professional interface.

Comment: Are you using a [CBitmapButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3y45xs0.aspx)? At any rate, the code you provided is insufficient to answer your question. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So your button should havec exactly the same look when it is sidabled as when it is enabled ? This would be very confusing for the user. He would try to click on the button and then he'd wonder why nothing happens.

Comment: @IInspectable I created a button over dialog box then for this button I tried to put a bitmap image to arrive at  this point I defined a member of `CButton` as: `CButton m_Close;` and then in `OnInitDialog()` a line of code included as follows : `m_Close.SetBitmap(LoadBitmap(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)));`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes you are right but If you already paid attention to a standard dialog box of a Company like **Microsoft**, for example when a download window opens, during the procedure when the progress bar is increasing, Next or Finish buttons are pale or colorless however still you can see background of this button. I'm trying to modify the dialog like that.

Comment: @Jessica: just tried what you did and it works well here: the image is still there when the button is disabled. Could you edit your question and add an image ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz A snapshot of the close button after writing EnableWindow included to the above question. My original code is a little bit nested perhaps I should w check it.

Comment: @Jessica please show also a snapshot of the enabled button and post and excerpt of the .rc file containing the definition of the button.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Please Check out the modified question.

Comment: @Jessica I don't see what's wrong with your code apart the `bool Flag` stuff. I suggest to start a dummy project from scratch (which is what I did). This dummy project should work as it works here. Then you look what might be different between your project and the dummy project.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I defined a new MFC project and created a button to control a close button. EnableWindow function works well in this project but when I define the same button control in the main project EnableWindow function doesn't work, I don't know why!!. By the way, thanks alot..

Comment: It could be the bitmap, try to use the bitmap from the dummy project in the real project and the other way round and look what happens. This might giove you some further ideas.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I already put a bitmap. In the dummy project it works well as I expected but in the real project doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I'm out of options now. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to change the signature of the OnBnClickedOK function. The MFC library code that calls it has no provision for adding an extra parameter.

You should also review the difference between = and == in an if statement.